# Anything to zero power equals one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am in Adv. Algebra 2 and I have a question. Firstly, would like to say I haven't taken algebra in a year due to geometry (stupid order they do but oh well) and I have a question understanding this: $(x+5)^{0}$. That would be $x^{0} + 5^{0}$ which then, wouldn't that be $1 + 1$ since anything that has a power of $0 = 1$? Maybe I misunderstood but that's what I got.

Comment: $(a+b)^t=a^t+b^t$ only if $t=1$.

Comment: @ajotatxe Don't you need to distribute the exponent though?

Comment: You don't need and you mustn't.

Comment: Exponents generally don't distribute over addition. Try $2^2+2^2$ and $(2+2)^2$, for example. On the other hand, exponents distribute over multiplication. $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$

Comment: @ajotatxe Are you able to explain why then? Just so I can relearn and understand it better

Comment: @ajotatxe or $t=p$ a prime, and characteristic is $p$.

Comment: @CaptainCaboose Rather, you need to explain a claim for why a property holds as opposed to claiming it might not hold in general. Try examples like the one suggested above and you can see it for yourself.

Comment: @Shuri2060 Yeah, I got it now, I remember. I feel such an idiot lol

Comment: I'd also like to add $0^0$ is not $1$ unless it is defined to be so in context (relating to the title)

Comment: To address the question stated by the title, in many contexts raising something to the zero power gives one.  E.g. [Why does any nonzero number to the zeroth power = 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121796/why-does-any-nonzero-number-to-the-zeroth-power-1)

Comment: @CaptainCaboose At least take solace in the fact that you're not alone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream

Comment: You shouldn't study advanced algebra before you mastered elementary algebra. I wonder if I'm at a mathematics site: nobody so much as mentioned the binomial theorem, $(a+b)^n=\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}a^k\,b^{n-k}$, **that's** how exponents "distribute".

Comment: @ProfessorVector , maybe the reason nobody's quoting the binomial theorem in this context is precisely because of the first sentence in your comment. Throwing a bunch of sum signs and binomial coefficients at someone who's working on the basics seems a bit heavy-handed, no?

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs My teachers didn't seem to think so, but... well, "mathematics site" is open to interpretation, after all. But he **is** studying **advanced** algebra, now, whatever that means in the case at hand.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I don't know. I do my best to meet the student where the seem to be, according to what they write. The name of the course tells me a lot less than the content presented. A concrete example of the $n=2$ case of the binomial theorem seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs Please, don't get me wrong: that's not a bad method when you are teaching, and your answer _was_ accepted, so...I was just wondering. But then, I seem to remember that I've read somewhere this site is about mathematics _at any level_. And certainly, a question is more likely to get downvoted because the OP doesn't know MathJax, not because he doesn't know (or care) what is 1+1.

Comment: @ProfessorVector , are you being sarcastic? Why? This site certainly is about mathematics *at any level*, and the fact that a few people didn't cite the binomial theorem on this question is in no way evidence against that. If you think it should be cited, you're welcome to post an answer doing so; I'll upvote it. However, I fail to see how snarky comments such as, "I wonder if I'm at a mathematics site," improve anything. Don't we try to maintain a more collegial atmosphere here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, exponents do not distribute over addition. To start with the simplest example, $(a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b)$. Applying the distributive rule, we see that this is the same as $a(a+b)+b(a+b) = a^2 + ab + ab + b^2$, which is different from $a^2+b^2$. This can be seen geometrically, too: A square built on a side of length $a+b$ has greater area than the square with side length $a$, combined with the square with side length $b$.

You can also see your result if you consider order of operations, and substitute an actual number for $x$. Let's consider $x=3$. Then we have:

$$(x+5)^0=(3+5)^0=8^0=1,$$

because Parentheses come before Exponents in PEMDAS.

Answer (score 1):

Exponents do *not* distribute for addition for any power other than 1.

Consider a numerical example to prove this:

$(a+b)^{\ n}$

Choose any two real numbers for $a$ and $b$. Let's choose $a = 4$ and $b=2$ arbitrarily. For $n$, let's bound it to $2$ for simplicity.

By your logic:

$$(4+2)^2 = 4^2 + 2^2 = 20$$

But as you should know in your classroom, PEMDAS mandates terms under parentheses are operated on first. Thus,

$$(6)^2 = 36$$

And this can be demonstrated by using binomial expansion. For $n$ = 2, the answer is in the form:

$$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$$

$$16 + 4 + 2(4)(2) = 36$$

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you do not distribute exponents through parentheses. Positive integer exponents are a short hand for repeated multiplication: $x^n = x\cdot x \cdot ...\cdot x$ n times.

We also have a rule that says that any negative exponentiation can be rewritten as positive exponentiation of the reciprocal: $x^{-n} = \frac{1}{x^n}$.

Finally, addition of exponents can be expressed as follows: $x^n * x^m = x^{n+m}$.

So what is $x^0$? Zero can be written as n + -n. So $x^0 = x^{n + -n}$. But that can be rewritten as $x^n * x^{-n}$. That's the same as $\frac{x^n}{x^n} = 1$

Comment: This post is plain wrong, and the upvoters apparently do not see or care that $x^0$ is **NOT** $x^n / x^n$ when $x=0$ and $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The Freshman's dream. There's a bit to take in here.

First, you must remember that exponentiation is multiplication. This is the same way we think $2^4 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 16$. Now, with binomials, the same deal holds:

$$ (x+y)^4 = (x+y)(x+y)(x+y)(x+y) $$

But with the power zero, it's something we call an empty product, which we take to be equal to one. That is,

$$ (x + y)^0 = 1 $$

You've done what many elementary algebra students do, and think that distributing the exponents through the binomial is allowed. This is only allowed in a more advanced sense, when $x$ and $y$ are members of a commutative ring of characteristic $p$ - a prime. Of course, this is done in abstract algebra, a course math majors take in their junior or senior year of college.

Point is, anything to the zero is one, and you cannot distribute exponents through a binomial (for now).