How does set theory justify defining zero to the zeroth power as 1?
$$0^0=|\text{Hom}_{\text{sets}}(\emptyset,\emptyset)|=1$$
I don't know how to use the math text so bear with me.
Supposedly according to this $0^0$ by definition is $1$. Which I'm not sure and would love for someone to explain what it means. I know
$\emptyset$ is the empty set, so is it like: by definition $0^0$ is the empty set to the power of empty set has only one possibility which makes by definition $1$, so $0^0$ by definition has to be $1$.

Please explain in detail what does  $Hom{sets}(a,b)$ mean for you. Is it the set of all homomorphism

I've made some of the MathJax changes; please check that the changes reflect your intention, and then edit your post to complete the changes. You can consult the MathJax link as needed for instructions.

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225020 and many other questions which can be easily found using site search (keywords "empty set" "function" "0^0" etc.).

@DrPotato It's the set of morphisms in the category of sets, so just the set of maps.

Even if both the domain and codomain are the empty set, there stil exists one morphism: the only one that goes from empty to empty, given by any correspondance rule. This is the same morphism independently of the given relation of sets for all elements in the [empty] domain, their image under these morphisms/relations are the same.

This question is similar to: Power Set and Empty Set question. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

$\operatorname{Hom}_{
\operatorname{Set}}(A,B)$ denotes the set of all functions $A \to B$. (More specifically, this notation means all of the morphisms $A \to B$ in the category of sets, where the morphisms are functions; but if you don't know category theory don't worry about that detail.) A function $f: A \to B$ is defined as a subset $f \subseteq A \times B$ such that for every $a \in A$ there is a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.  If $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \emptyset$, then there is exactly one such function, namely $f = \emptyset$.  $f = \emptyset$ vacuously satisfies the criterion for being a function, and furthermore it is the only function: for if $f \neq \emptyset$ then there is some $(a,b) \in f$ and then $a \in \emptyset$, a contradiction.
All of that is to say that $\operatorname{Hom}_{
\operatorname{Set}}(\emptyset, \emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$ and so $|\operatorname{Hom}_{
\operatorname{Set}}(\emptyset, \emptyset)| = 1$. So what does that have to do with $0^0$? Well, for nonempty finite sets $A$, $B$ we have $\operatorname{Hom}_{
\operatorname{Set}}(A, B) = |B|^{|A|}$. For example there are $2^3 = 8$ functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2\}$ (we have two choices of where to send $1$, two choices of where to send $2$, two choices of where to send $3$.) So, if we define $0^0 = 1$ then this pattern holds for all empty sets as well. So it's an argument that we ought to define $0^0 = 1$ instead of some other choice.  Whether that's a proof or not depends on your definition of $a^b$.  If you define $a^b$ so that $a^b$ is the cardinality of $\operatorname{Hom}_{
\operatorname{Set}}(A,B)) = \{\emptyset\}$, where $A = \{1,2, \ldots, a\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, \ldots, b\}$ then $|\operatorname{Hom}_{
\operatorname{Set}}(\emptyset, \emptyset)| = 1$ proves that $0^0 = 1$. If you define $a^b$ in some other way, then this is not a proof, but it nonetheless a convenient fact.
Note that sometimes we denote $\operatorname{Hom}_{
\operatorname{Set}}(A,B)$ by $B^A$, so that (if $0^0 = 1$) we have $|B^A| = |B|^{|A|}$ for $A,B$ are finite sets. I've avoided using the notation $B^A$ above to avoid any confusion with the operation on natural numbers $b^a$.

It might be worth noting that if $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are cardinal numbers, then the notation $\kappa^\lambda$ admits two interpretations: as the set of functions $\lambda\to\kappa$, or as a cardinal number. These two interpretations are closely linked: in set theory, the cardinal number $\kappa^\lambda$ is typically defined as the cardinality of the set $\kappa^\lambda$.

Please don't answer duplicate questions. This is against site policy. See here.

There are a few tricky things going on here. Rather than landing right on the empty set with a bang, let's try to get there bit by bit.
Suppose we have a set of people $A$ and a set of teams $B$. We'll start with $A = \{\text{Pat}, \text{Quinn}\}$ and $B = \{\text{Rams}, \text{Seahawks}, \text{Tigers}\}$. Each person has a favorite team, and for some reason, we want to know how many different ways the people in $A$ can choose a favorite team from $B$. (They don't have to pick different teams; two people can have the same favorite team.)
One way to answer this question is to just list them:
$$
\text{Pat} \to \text{Rams}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Rams} \\
\text{Pat} \to \text{Rams}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Seahawks} \\
\text{Pat} \to \text{Rams}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Tigers} \\
\text{Pat} \to \text{Seahawks}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Rams} \\
\text{Pat} \to \text{Seahawks}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Seahawks} \\
\text{Pat} \to \text{Seahawks}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Tigers} \\
\text{Pat} \to \text{Tigers}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Rams} \\
\text{Pat} \to \text{Tigers}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Seahawks} \\
\text{Pat} \to \text{Tigers}, \text{Quinn} \to \text{Tigers}
$$
However, we can be a bit more systematic about this. We can recognize that Pat can choose any of $3$ teams and so can Quinn, independently of Pat's choice. That leads to a total of $3 \times 3 = 3^2 = 9$ combined choices.
This kind of reasoning allows us to answer the question for larger sets $A$ and $B$. Notice that for the purposes of this question, we don't care what the elements of $A$ and $B$ are, only their sizes or cardinalities. We denote these cardinalities with $|A|$ and $|B|$.
For this example, $|A| = 2$ and $|B| = 3$. But suppose we had $|A| = 5$ people and $|B| = 7$ teams. Then each of those $5$ people would have $7$ choices, and the total number of combined choices would be $7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 = 7^5 = 16\,807$. Just imagine trying to list all those out!
More generally then, the number $N$ of combined choices would be
$$
N = |B|^{|A|}
$$
Now, let's start restricting things. If there's only $|A| = 1$ person, then the number of combined choices is just the number of that one person's choices, which is $|B|$:
$$
N = |B|^1 = |B|
$$
On the other hand, if there's only $|B| = 1$ choice, then each of the $|A|$ people can only make that one choice, so the number of combined choices is also only $1$:
$$
N = 1^{|A|} = 1
$$
What if there's $|B| = 0$ choices—that is, $B$ is the empty set? Then there are no ways for each person in $A$ to choose a favorite team, so the number of combined choices is $0$:
$$
N = 0^{|A|} = 0
$$
We seem to be on a collision course with $N = 1$ when $|A| = |B| = 0$, which doesn't fit this rule! But there's a twist.

The twist is that if there are no people—that is, if $A$ is the empty set and $|A| = 0$—the number of combined choices is $1$, not $0$. How can this be? There are no people to make any choices; how can there be any combined choices?
The reason there's actually one combined choice is that a combined choice is simply a way to map each person in $A$ to a choice in $B$. When $B$ was the empty set, there was no way to do that mapping because each person had no choice available. But when $A$ is the empty set, there is a way: The empty mapping qualifies, because each person in $A$ is making a choice. Or equivalently, there is no person in $A$ who does not make a choice, because there is no person in $A$ to begin with! Hence the number of combined choices is $1$, not $0$.
This is a rather non-intuitive way to interpret these words in ordinary English, because there's no actual choosing going on. But there is a choice function—namely, the empty function. And it makes actual numerical sense:

In our original example, $2$ people each made one of $3$ choices, so there were $3^2 = 9$ combined choices.

If we take away one of the people (leaving one), then the number of combined choices should be reduced by a factor of $3$, and sure enough, there are $3^1 = 3$ combined choices.

If we take away another person (leaving none), then again the number of combined choices should be reduced by a factor of $3$, and true to form, there is $3^0 = 1$ combined choice.


We can't quite reason this way when $|B| = 0$, because it leads to the expression $0/0$. But recognizing that an empty set $A$ of people can be mapped to any set $B$ in a single way motivates the common assignment $0^0 = 1$.
I've worded this in rather informal language, but it can be formalized and carry forward essentially the intuition given above (hopefully).

Please don't answer duplicate questions. This is against site policy. See here.
