# Raising something to the zeroth power is one. This works in many contexts. What is the connection between the contexts?

Tags: exponentiation

I learned that the reason $a^0$ is defined as $1$ is for consistency with the rule $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$. However, the fact that $a^0$ is $1$ is used in contexts outside of the algebraic manipulation seen in the prior sentence. It is unclear to me what the relationship is between those contexts and the definition of $a^0$.

For instance, we can expand an integer $k$ in some base $b$ as $k = \sum_{i=0} c_ib^i.$ This expansion is predicated on the fact that $b^0=1$.

Another context comes from looking at the maximum number of nodes at level L in a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree): $2^L$. If we let $L=0$ for the root node we get the correct maximum number of root nodes: 1.

Are these examples somehow fundamentally connected to the algebraic motivation for defining $a^0$ as $1$? If so, what is that connection?

Comment: See for example the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2121796/362967).

Comment: I don't think those really answer my question. They explain why $a^0=1$ from an algebraic perspective, and I understand why it's useful in that context, but I want to know the connection of that definition to the use of that identity in other contexts.

Comment: I don't see why for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2121810/362967) is not sufficient. In both your example contexts you have exactly such a sequence of powers.